# Pull button disabled in xcode6

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, gitlab

I am using gitlab for source control.when i give pull request in xcode the pull button at right corner is disabled.so i unable to pull the code.

I already added .DS_Store file to .gitignore file but still am facing the problem.

Comment: Are you making sure you are connected to network? Can you fetch the remote?

Comment: ya sure i am able fetch remote